# Get the real time of a user

Tags: javascript, angular, google-api

I'm facing a problem to get the real 'trusted' user time, preventing them to cheat if they change their computer's time.

Weather I use a plain date object, or moment timezone or even google timezone api I just can't get the 'real' time of a user if I try manipulating the current time.

If we are at 20:00 (no matther the location) and the user tempers with the time to set it as 11:00 then I always end up with that time and not the real one, either by

```
const time = new Date();
const timestamp = (time.getTime() / 1000 + time.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);
const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=-31.369926900000003,-64.2218601&timestamp=1568396292&key=MY_API_KEY';
this.httpDuplicate.get(url ).subscribe((res: any) => {
   if (res) {
      const dst = res.dstOffset;
      const raw = res.rawOffset;
      const fixed = (timestamp + raw + dst) * 1000;
      const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
      const currentTime = momenttz().tz(timezone).format();
      console.warn('initial time ', new Date(time), 
                   ' - google time ', new Date(fixed), 
                   ' - moment timezone ', currentTime);
      // all these values are wrong and point to 11:00 rather than 20:00
   }
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this ? What I want in the end is to get the right time for a certain position... clearly not trusting the user's system time, but do trust its location (though there are ways to alter this as well)

Comment: Are you interested in their current time (like trying to figure out if it's "really" 8:00 PM in the user's local time zone)? If so, there's know way to know that unless you've got a GPS tracker on the user. If you're interested in *duration*, however, like measuring how long the user is working at a task, that's another matter.

Comment: There is nothing you can do to make the user's clock the current time.... not sure what you are really after.

Comment: If you can elaborate a bit on what problem it is that you're trying to solve, we can probably help you figure out an alternative solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it fails is because you reference the Date object you made based on the user's client time ('time' variable).

If you don't trust the system time, you'd have to get the time from somewhere else, like an external server that you do trust, or the backend of your application if you have one (server time).
For example: http://worldtimeapi.org/

Of course, you'd also need the user's location in that case. I can imagine you don't trust that either since you also don't trust the time, so in that scenario there's no way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Despite the fact I can't trust 100% that the location is real this won't be as likely than tamping the system time. So for the moment this could be a solution to me, based on the location getting the time for that position in the world. Thanks a lot!